# using google js api to authenticate the user and get the google id of the user

Tags: authentication, google-api, google-api-js-client

I'm using this as a reference:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/wiki/Authentication

I'm trying to authenticate a user and then fetch his/her google_id after auth.

I have a button called "login with google" and when the user clicks on it, it launches a popup that asks if he/she wants to give authorization to the app. After that 
it throws an error saying "bad request" and "400 not found" when it tries to do a GET on this

https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/plus/v1/***/*****/***** 400 (Bad Request)

I'm using the same code as described in the above mentioned api.

I also crosschecked the api key and client id, but everything seems fine.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to move to [Google+ Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/). It uses the same JS client but does a lot of the hard work for you.